# IntelliJ through X11 "Searching everything" doesn't always get focus

Tags: intellij-idea, x11

When I hit "double shift" I start typing but it doesn't type anything in the prompt, when I try to click on it with the mouse it disappears.
Once in a while it does seem to work for one time and I don't understand why it does succeed. Any suggestions regarding this issue?

Comment: X11 as in Linux, or OS X?  Or are you using X11 through the network?

Comment: sorry for not specifying. I am using a windows 8.1 machine with X Server running. The intellij is installed on a VM that runs CentOS. The VM is on my PC but for all intents and purposes it is somewhere on the network.

Comment: ...Is there any particular reason that you don't just install it on Windows 8.1?  This is a very awkward use case; not one I've encountered before.

Comment: My dev machine is the VM. I know it's a weird setup but it is what it is.
When I use the intellij through the VM console it works fine, only through the X11 the issue happens. I would like to use it in this way.

Comment: This is a known bug: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-124160. Feel free to vote for it, so that hopefully it will get fixed sooner :)

Comment: Thanks. I guess it has nothing to do with X11 then

Comment: This one remains a problem even till today, I was using Intellij 2017.2.4 with rhel 7. Have to go back to 2017.1.5.